# Is it possible to create a LinkedList implementation with O(1) Insertion, Deletion, and O(1) Access to Minimum?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

Assume you have unlimited space complexity for this problem. I believe I was showed the solution and I have completely forgotten it. If I recall correctly, one solution involved a stack to keep track of the min and the other involved adding a data values to the LinkedList Node.

A Minimum-Heap implementation would result in Log(n) insertion and deletion but is there a way to make it O(1)?

What would be the implementation of a data structure that can do this, if it is even possible.

Comment: Off-topic here. Should go to https://cs.stackexchange.com/ ... It won't be a linked list. But read about [red-black trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is off-topic here.

Comment: Wouldn't this let you sort a list of `n` elements in `O(n)` time? That doesn't seem possible, unless there's some further restriction on the elements...

Answer (score 3):

If you had such a datastructure, you could sort n items using O(n) comparisons: add them to the list, then repeatedly find the minimum and remove it.

So it's not possible in general for this datastructure to exist with these performance bounds.